# Read an XML style file using PHP

Tags: php, string, parsing, xml-parsing

I am trying to retrieve data from this XML style file :

```
<Product_Group>
  <Product_Group_ID>131</Product_Group_ID>
  <Product_Group_Title>Thanks for the Memories</Product_Group_Title>
  <Products>
    <On_Sale_Date>03/01/12 00:00:00.000</On_Sale_Date>
    <ISBN>9780007233694</ISBN>
    <Title>Thanks for the Memories</Title>
    <Format>Paperback</Format>
    <Sub_Format/>
    <CoverImageURL_Small>http://www.harpercollins.com/harperimages/isbn/small/4/9780007233694.jpg</CoverImageURL_Small>
  </Products>
</Product_Group>
```

I am using following code but this seems to retrieve nothing. any help in fixing this issues would be highly appreciated

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
//$xml= $response;
$updates = array();
//loop through all the entry(s) in the feed
for ($i=0; $i<count($xml->Product_Group); $i++)
{
    //get the id from entry
    $ISBN = $xml->entry[$i]->ISBN;

    //get the account link
    $Title = $xml->entry[$i]->Title;

    //get the tweet
    $Product_Group_SEO_Copy = $xml->entry[$i]->Product_Group_SEO_Copy;  
}
```

Comment: use `libxml_get_errors()` to see any errors generated as a result of loading the string into SimpleXML.

Comment: Seems to retrieve nothing does not say much. What does `var_dump($xml)` gives to you? And did you notice that you're not accessing `<Products>` but `<Product_Group>`?

Answer (score 0):

1) It is not valid XML. What warnings do you see? You'll need to fix them for `simplexml_load_string` to work properly.

For example, `</CoverImageURL_Small>` should be `<CoverImageURL_Small/>`

2) Assuming that `Product_Group` is not your actual document root (if it is than `$xml` points to it already and `$xml->Product_Group` will not work) then you can access each element like

`$xml->Product_Group->Products[$i]->ISBN;`

3) It's usually simpler to use a `foreach` loop than a `for` loop when dealing with simplexml

```
foreach($xml->Product_Group->Products as $p)
{
    $ISBN = $p->ISBN;
    //var_dump($ISBN);
}
```

Comment: I am not seeing any error. It just simply does not parse any thing.

Comment: the root is : <OpenBook_API> and not XML : do you think that could be the issue??